# Catalina and old application compatibility regarding new file system access rights

Tags: catalina, permission

I am trying to make [Time Lapse Assembler](http://www.dayofthenewdan.com/projects/time-lapse-assembler-1/) work on Catalina but no luck so far. I can open the UI and input files etc but when it comes to writing a destination file it gives an error without giving much explanation.

My guess is that it has something to do with Catalina's increased per operation access rights but I am not sure.

I tried to give write access to Time Lapse Assembler on *~/Downloads*, I tried to write on a SD card, tried to create a file with (`chmod 777`) everybody but no luck either.

I wonder if there is a trick to explicitly disable checks or if there is any other trick to make Time Lapse Assembler work on Catalina.

Exact error message on the pop up dialog is: "Error encoding file: There was an error accessing the destination file. File may already exist and be opened in another application. Close other applications and try again.

Comment: I assume you are talking about https://imageoptim.com/mac, right? Did you try to reach out to the developer?

Comment: I got confused about application name. It is Time Lapse Assembler not ImageOptim. I have fixed the original question.

Comment: So it's http://www.dayofthenewdan.com/projects/time-lapse-assembler-1/ then? Question about reaching out to the developer stays the same though? :-)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this seems to be a question best answered by support from the publisher of the application

Comment: Per your last paragraph in the question... did you try saving it under a different name?  Do you have enough space on the destination?  You didn't get a permission denied error, you got an error that it couldn't write the file because it may be locked by something else.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and couldn't figure out a fix.

Turns out, though, that the built-in `/Applications/QuickTime Player.app` has a very similar feature: see `File > Open Image Sequence`.

(I'm using macOS 12.4, but I think this feature has been present since perhaps at least 2011...)